# Convert Json to apex by adminbooster class and testclass

Tags: apex, json, list, parser

How do I use the json2apex tool. I generated an apex code and I am trying to split this in an apex class and testclass but get the error:

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void parse(String) from the type invoicesTest

Class:

```
//
//Generated by AdminBooster
//

public class invoices{
    public cls_invoiceList[] invoiceList;
    class cls_invoiceList {
        public String customerId;   //12345abcd
        public String addressId;    //1000AA25
        public String invoiceId;    //c000X000021KuMi
        public String invoiceType;  //MontlyPayment
        public String invoiceTypeLocalized; //Pending
        public String invoiceDate;  //2016-08-14T00:00:00
        public String DueDate;  //2016-09-14T00:00:00
        public String invoiceNumber;    //123456
        public String startDate;    //2016-07-01T00:00:00
        public String endDate;  //2017-07-01T00:00:00
        public String Description;  //july 2016
        public Double amount;   //100.1
        public Double vatAmount;    //50.5
        public Double totalAmount;  //150.6
    }
    public static invoices parse(String json){
        return (invoices) System.JSON.deserialize(json, invoices.class);
    }
}

Testclass:


@isTest
public class invoicesTest {
    static testMethod void testParse() {
        String json=        '{'+
        '  "invoiceList": ['+
        ' {'+
        '"customerId": "12345abcd",'+
        '"addressId": "1000AA25",'+
        '"invoiceId": "c000X000021KuMi",'+
        '"invoiceType": "MontlyPayment",'+
        '"invoiceTypeLocalized": "Pending",'+
        '"invoiceDate": "2016-08-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"DueDate": "2016-09-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"invoiceNumber": "123456",'+
        '"startDate": "2016-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"endDate": "2017-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"Description": "july 2016",'+
        '"amount": 100.10,'+
        '"vatAmount": 50.50,'+
        '"totalAmount": 150.60'+
        '},'+
        '{'+
        '"customerId": "12345abcd",'+
        '"addressId": "1000AA25",'+
        '"invoiceId": "c000X000021KuMi",'+
        '"invoiceType": "MontlyPayment",'+
        '"invoiceTypeLocalized": "Pending",'+
        '"invoiceDate": "2016-08-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"DueDate": "2016-09-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"invoiceNumber": "123456",'+
        '"startDate": "2016-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"endDate": "2017-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"Description": "july 2016",'+
        '"amount": 100.10,'+
        '"vatAmount": 50.50,'+
        '"totalAmount": 150.60'+
        '},'+
        '{'+
        '"customerId": "12345abcd",'+
        '"addressId": "1000AA25",'+
        '"invoiceId": "c000X000021KuMi",'+
        '"invoiceType": "MontlyPayment",'+
        '"invoiceTypeLocalized": "Pending",'+
        '"invoiceDate": "2016-08-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"DueDate": "2016-09-14T00:00:00",'+
        '"invoiceNumber": "123456",'+
        '"startDate": "2016-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"endDate": "2017-07-01T00:00:00",'+
        '"Description": "july 2016",'+
        '"amount": 100.10,'+
        '"vatAmount": 50.50,'+
        '"totalAmount": 150.60'+
        '}'+
        '      ]}'+
        '';
        invoices obj = parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `invoices obj = invoices.parse(json);`

Comment: @HemantJain please place this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse` is a static method and its in a different class. So you need to reference using the class name.

So it should be called like this:

```
invoices obj = invoices.parse(json);
```